# How to filter Recycle Bin out of WinMerge compare?

Tags: windows-10, winmerge, file-filter

In windows 10, I would like to exclude Recycle Bin files from WinMerge compare on different harddrives (the harddrives may be add or remove from the computer so ideally drive letter should be any.)

Follwing the manual ( http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html )

I tried (filename: RecycleBin.flt , located in the right folder)

```
## This is a directory/file filter for WinMerge
name: RecycleBin
desc: Recycle bin

## This is an inclusive filter
## (Includes everything except items matching the specified rule. )
def: include

^\\$RECYCLE.BIN\
```

I also tried multiple variant of
    ^\$RECYCLE.BIN\
such as

```
^\\\$RECYCLE.BIN\
f:\$RECYCLE.BIN\
F:\\$RECYCLE.BIN
F:\\\$RECYCLE.BIN
```

None of these worked.

Comment: I found an alternate solution to my specific problem which was that $RECYCLE.BIN results were cause a lot of "noise" when reading the result. The alternate solution was to g in View menu and select Tree view. That way the whole $RECYCLE.BIN holds on one single line and anyway I think that presentation make everything easier to read for me. However, this does not reply to the question itself that was about filters. Hence, the question stays open.

Comment: look at the convention used in this persons filter, which includes that. http://shookit.com/wiki/index.php?title=Winmerge  There is odd space there, different?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a gazillion years since this was asked, but here's how to get  it to work.  You have to use the backslash as an escape character for both the $ and the . in the name for the folder.  Hope that helps!

````````
## This is a directory/file filter template for WinMerge
name: Ignore Recycle Bin
desc: Ignore the Recycle Bin folder when comparing folders

## Select if filter is inclusive or exclusive
## Inclusive (loose) filter lets through all items not matching rules
## Exclusive filter lets through only items that match to rule
## include or exclude
def: include

## Filters for filenames begin with f:
## Filters for directories begin with d:
## (Inline comments begin with " ##" and extend to the end of the line)

##f: \.ext$ ## Filter for filename

d: \$RECYCLE\.BIN ## Filter for directory
```````

Regards,
Jeff
````````